# CakePHP 2.5.5 - catching error when connection to different server has database missing

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp

I have got a situation. I am dropping default DB connection and connecting to different database on the fly. I want to delete new database if it is found. If new database exists in new connection it all works fine. However if the database in new connection is missing it throws exception which I am unable to catch. I want to know whether database in new connection misses and show client an error saying that "the database you were trying to delete had already been deleted"

Here is my code:

```
ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')->disconnect();
ConnectionManager::drop('default');

try {
    ConnectionManager::create('Default', $this->config);
    $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
} catch (MissingDatabaseException $e) {
  die($e->getMessage());
}
```

In the code above it has an exception in the ConnectionManager::create() method when i try to connection with new settings passed in $this->config.

How do I do this to check db existence before trying to create a connection or capture exception before it is eventually sent to browser in create() method. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that the missing connection is throwing an exception? If that's the case then that's surely what you want so that you can handle the case of a missing database.

Comment: Or is it that you're not able to catch the exception before the framework does, in which case you could broaden the type of exception you are trying to catch.